# Duvida com Jquery e select

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, twig

Estou dando manutenção num codigo de outro programador e estou enfrentando dificuldades em dois select.

Preciso pegar a hora de cada campo e somar esse intervalo, até ai tudo bem ja fiz uns testes usando a lib Moment.js e ela me atende perfeitamente.
O que estou tendo dor de cabeça é em pegar os valores dos select.

No codigo existe mistura de HTML puro com de um framework de render de pagina, TWIG.
Ja tentei varias formas de ler o name, e sempre me retorna Undefined.

Segue o fragmento do codigo.

```
<fieldset class="datas">
            <legend class="text-center bg-default border-control">Datas</legend>
            <div id="container-data" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">

                <div class="form-group linha-data-template hidden">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputDataTemplate">Data</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="inputDataTemplate" id="inputDataTemplate" type="text" class="inputDataTemplate form-control input-sm" placeholder="99/99/9999" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[2][0][1][1-9]" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-sm btn-calendar" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 ">
                        <label class="control-label" for="cbHorarioIni">Horário</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{ form_dropdown('cbHorarioIniTemplate', horarios, agendai.A106_Codigo, 'id="cbHorarioIniTemplate" class="input-sm form-control"') }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
                        <label class="control-label" for="cbHorarioFim">às</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{ form_dropdown('cbHorarioFimTemplate', horarios, agendai.A106_Codigo, 'id="cbHorarioFimTemplate" class="input-sm form-control cbHorarioFimTemplate"') }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <a id="removeData" style="cursor: pointer;"><h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></span></h5></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% for nro in 1..agendai.nro_datas %}
                <div class="form-group linha-data">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputData">Data</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="inputData[]" type="text" class="form-control data input-sm data-esconder" placeholder="99/99/9999" required maxlength="10" pattern="[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[2][0][1][1-9]" value="{{set_value('inputData',agendai.datas[loop.index0].inputData)}}" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-sm btn-calendar" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label" for="cbHorarioIni">Horário</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{ form_dropdown('cbHorarioIni[]', horarios, set_value('cbHorarioIni', agendai.datas[loop.index0].cbHorarioIni), 'class="input-sm form-control selectpicker"') }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
                        <label class="control-label" for="cbHorarioFim">às</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{ form_dropdown('cbHorarioFim[]', horarios, set_value('cbHorarioFim', agendai.datas[loop.index0].cbHorarioFim), 'class="input-sm form-control selectpicker"') }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 green">
                        {% if loop.index == 1%}
                        <a id="addData" style="cursor: pointer;"><h5 class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus green "></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Adicionar Data</h5></a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a id="removeData" style="cursor: pointer;"><h5 ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red "></span></h5></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
</fieldset>
```

https://pastebin.com/vieLVB8Z

Comment: Como é código que usa para pegar o valor do select?

Comment: Esta neste link do pastebin.

O codigo JS nao ta trazendo nada, sempre undefined

Comment: Mas eu não sei qual é código js que vc usa.

Comment: Ok...
Este é o codigo que estou tentando usar pra capturar o valor dos select.

https://pastebin.com/jK06vqrV
Como to fazendo teste nao me preocupei com nomes de variaveis mais condizentes.

Comment: Faça um teste rápido no console do chrome, coloque esse código e de enter: `$('input[name=inputData]')` pelo menos ele deve mostrar todos os elementos (tem mais de um com esse nome) seleciondos. Não tem como dar um `val()` em um array, precisa especificar qual elemento é ou percorrer ele.

Comment: Fiz e retornou isso.


$('input[name=inputData]')
Object[]

Comment: Fiz pelo firebug

Comment: Vc fez assim: `console.log($("input[name='inputData']"));` ?

Comment: Fiz desse jeito retornou

** console.log($("input[name='inputData']"));
undefined **

Comment: Quando coloco :
$('.cbhoraini option').eq(0).val(); no debug e peço pra rodar ele me traz o primeiro valor , se incluir outra data com horario, e mudar do eq(0) para eq(1) ele nao pega o valor

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', 'seletor do teu select' , function(e) {
        alert ( $(this).val() );
});
```

Não entendi pq vc usou o h1 como parâmetro, mas isso aí deve mostrar o que vc deseja.